# Is an expression interpreted differently in irb and rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, irb

I have just noticed

User.where("id = '309'")

works in IRB console. However it doesn't work in my controller. I wonder why?

In contrast, User.find(309) works in both irb console and my controller.

In my controller,

```
before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update], 

private  
  def correct_user  
      @user = User.where("id = '309'")  
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)  
 end  
end
```

This does not work. The view webpage does not open with no error message.

If User.find(309) instead. It will work by going to correct view webpage.

Comment: Ruby2.1.5, rails 4.2.0

Comment: It doesn't work because it doesn't find the record? Or because it  generates an error?

Comment: In contrast, User.find(309) works in both irb console and my controller.

Comment: Show us the code running in the controller. Are you sure that console and web app are talking to the same database?

Comment: In contrast, User.find(309) works in both irb console and my controller.

In my controller, 

before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update], 

private
   def correct_user
      @user = User.where("id = '309'")
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)

    end
end

This does not work. The view webpage does not open with no error message.

If User.find(309) instead. It will work.

Comment: Please, don't post code here in the comments. Update your question with the code you want to show.

Comment: Yes, they both are talking to the same database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you may be expecting the same behavior from `User.find` and `User.where`. `User.find` will automatically grab an actual User, whereas `User.where` will grab a search query that sort of functions as an array. Try putting `.last` after the where. Like this:

```
@user = User.where("id = '309'").last
```

Comment: In fact. I wrote exactly about this in my blog today: http://rubyofftherails.blogspot.com.br/2016/05/adding-activerecord-relations.html

Comment: Thank you! msergeant and Almeida.